# using catalog file with saxon9he

Tags: xml, saxon

I'd like to use a catalog file to make Saxon shut up about not finding DTDs. Currently, I use dummy DTDS and emulate the required folder structure, but that's not ideal.

However, when I run the transformation, I get the following error:

```
Transformation failed: Failed to load Apache catalog resolver library
```

Here's how I call Saxon from Altova:

```
java -jar "F:\saxon9he.jar" -s:%1 -o:%2 -xsl:%3 -t -catalog:"catalog.xml"
```

I downloaded the xerces parser and took the resolver.jar from there. Is that already a mistake? (It said so here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/UseCatalog.html)

The `saxon9he.jar`, the `resolver.jar` and the `catalog.xml` are all in the same folder.

Here's the catalog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"> 
    <public 
       publicId="-//EG//DTD EG DITA Map//EN" 
       uri="dtds/maps.dtd"/>
    <public 
       publicId="-//EG//DTD EG DITA Composite//EN" 
       uri="dtds/topics.dtd"/>
</catalog>
```

Here's how the DTDs look in the files:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc_map PUBLIC "-//EG//DTD EG DITA Map//EN" "../../system/dtd/client/eg-docmap.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//EG//DTD EG DITA Composite//EN" "../../system/dtd/client/eg-dita.dtd">
```

I created the folder `dtd` which contains `maps.dtd` and `topics.dtd` (both files are empty).

I looked at this post: 
[How to use saxon built-in catalog feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165765/how-to-use-saxon-built-in-catalog-feature) but wasn't able to get a solution form that.

Is this still a bug or something? Or did I do something wrong?

**EDIT:**

Console output:

```
Loading catalog: \catalog.xml
Saxon-HE 9.6.0.4J from Saxonica
Java version 1.7.0_09
Stylesheet compilation time: 940.807978ms
Processing file:/F:/export/folders.xml
Using parser org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader
Building tree for file:/F:/export/folders.xml using class
net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Tree built in 3.841258ms
Tree size: 6 nodes, 0 characters, 6 attributes
Building tree for file:/F:/export/test/532a1069faf343d79c4ad37f8339aeda.map using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Error at template on line 33 of maps.xsl:
  I/O error reported by XML parser processing
  file:/F:/export/test/532a1069faf343d79c4ad37f8339aeda.map: F:\export\system\dtd\client\map.dtd (cannot find path)
I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/F:/export/test/532a1069faf343d79c4ad37f8339aeda.ditamap: F:\export\system\dtd\client\
map.dtd (cannot find path)
```

Comment: Can someone explain where exactly `resolver.jar` can be downloaded? Please, post a link.

Comment: I think I used this one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the -jar option if you want to load software from more than one JAR file. Use the -cp option to define the classpath containing all the required JARs, and specify your desired entry point (net.sf.saxon.Transform) explicitly.

Comment: I think I got it working now. However, now it says that it doesnt find the DTD although I put that DTD in the catalog file.

Comment: Looks like you're making progress. Getting catalogs working can be tricky. I assume your comment above is "just mentioning", there's obviously not enough information here to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I posted the output I get on the console now. What more information would you need?

Comment: Well it says it can't find `F:\export\system\dtd\client\map.dtd`. Is that where you expect it to be looking?

Comment: Well, I thought the catalog file is there to make saxon look in the path specified in the catalog and not in the path specified in the actual DTD. But yes, if I had the DTD, that's where it would have to be located.

Comment: It's not Saxon that's looking for the DTD, it's the XML parser. But when you use -catalog, Saxon gives the XML parser an EntityResolver that tells the XML parser to look in the catalog. Where is the name `F:\export\system\dtd\client\map.dtd` coming from? It's not in any of your examples. I suggest you raise a new question that shows your catalog and XML files and filestore layout in detail.

Comment: Incidentally, if I want to suppress DTD processing entirely, I usually find it much easier to supply an EntityResolver that does just that, rather than messing about with catalogs.

Comment: Okay, I raised a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804424/using-saxon9he-with-catalog-xml-file