# Saxon XQuery catalog files to override DTD URI?

Tags: xquery, saxon

I am trying to use a catalog file to override DTD location in XML files.  I tried following all of the tips here [How to use saxon built-in catalog feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165765/how-to-use-saxon-built-in-catalog-feature) but have been unable to get it to work.  I reduced to this simple example:

Confirmed version of Saxon:

```
C:\test>java net.sf.saxon.Query
No query file name
Saxon-HE 9.7.0.7J from Saxonica
...
```

My catalog file.  I tried to reduce to simplest (uriSuffix):

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <uriSuffix uriSuffix="bad.dtd"  uri="good.dtd" />
</catalog>
```

Confirmed resolver is in classpath and behaving as expected with catalog:

```
C:\test>java org.apache.xml.resolver.apps.resolver -c didcat.xml -u bad.dtd uri
Cannot find CatalogManager.properties
Resolve URI (uri):
        uri: bad.dtd
Result: file:/C:/test/good.dtd
```

Simple test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE a SYSTEM "bad.dtd">
<a>hello world</a>
```

Simple test.xql:

```
doc("test.xml")/a
```

Results:

```
C:\test>java net.sf.saxon.Query -t -catalog:didcat.xml test.xql
Loading catalog: didcat.xml
Saxon-HE 9.7.0.7J from Saxonica
Java version 1.8.0_101
Analyzing query from test.xql
Analysis time: 131.650519 milliseconds
Resolved URI: test.xml
        file:/C:/test/test.xml
Building tree for file:/C:/test/test.xml using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Error on line 2 column 6 of test.xql:
  FODC0002: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/test/test.xml:
  C:\test\bad.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
Query failed with dynamic error: I/O error reported by XML parser processing file:/C:/test/test.xml: C:\test\bad.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I tried a few different catalog techniques to override the DTD URI but none were successful.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve references to XML entities such as DTDs, you need to use the `systemSuffix` entry in the catalog, not the `uriSuffix` entry. Change your catalog to

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <systemSuffix systemSuffix="bad.dtd" uri="good.dtd" />
</catalog>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Worked perfectly.